# Transform project from windows-1256 to utf-8 charset, what's the right steps?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, arabic

I got a PHP & MySQL script that use windows-1256 charset, I now want to modify the whole script make it completely built on  utf-8 charset. starting from mysql DataBase to PHP files.

what is the right steps to achive that's??!!

Note: I use non-Latin language in script (Arabic language).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the database level, have a look at:

- [Turning MySQL data in latin1 to utf8 utf-8](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/01/turning_mysql_data_in_latin1_t.html)
- [PHP UTF-8 cheatsheet](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet)

As for your html pages, use this `meta` tag:

```
<meta charset=utf-8 />
```

And you can also use this header from php:

```
header('content-type: text/html charset=utf-8');
```

Or you might want to have a look at complete php-arabic solution here:

- http://www.ar-php.com/

Answer (score 0):

I found such solution:

[PHP & MySQL: Creating a website in your local language smoothly](http://www.tanzilo.com/2008/12/29/php-mysql-creating-a-website-in-your-local-language-smoothly/)