# Convert Windows-1256 to UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, encode, windows-1255

I get the contents of a web page by curl, with charset set to Windows-1256.

Now I want to insert this data into a MySQL database, with charset utf8_general_ci.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You might want to look in here first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592898/php-convert-windows-1256-encoded-text-to-utf-8

Comment: it didn't work so I post this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php):

```
$utf8 = iconv('windows-1256', 'utf-8', $win1256);
```

...although [`Supported character sets depend on the iconv implementation of your system.`](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.iconv.php), so YMMV.

If you want a 100% safe, works everywhere way to do this, the simplest thing to do would be to make a lookup table a use `str_replace()`.